# Modeling a plastic bottle with real polygons

Tags: modeling

How can I model this plastic bottle with real polygons?

[image]

As you can see, here are two waveforms:

[image]

---

Update: Thank you very much for your answers! I was able to create this first wavy  edge, but I am not able to create the second wavy edge with the answers below. When I add the shade smooth or subdivision surface, errors occur.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE! What have you tried so far to model this bottle, what causes you trouble?

Comment: Hi, Jasurbek.. Folks have been answering this question on the assumption that this is a transparent bottle, in which case the 'second wave' is actually the first wave, seen through the back.. there are only 2 peaks, and 2 troughs. That seems reasonable, given this reference. Could you give another view that illustrates the 'second wave' better?

Comment: Check out this tutorial, it may be helpful to you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38WoPppOHvQ&list=PL0B1F9143C605E433&index=586

Comment: you mean like this? https://snipboard.io/2tCuEs.jpg

Answer (score 8):

You could begin by a 32 vertex cylinder, create some horizontal edge loops and scale them down to follow the profile:

[image]

Symmetrize your cylinder on X and Y with the *Mirror* modifier, draw the wave with the knife tool:

[image]

Draw some other edge loops in order to change the topology around the wave:

[image]

Extrude the bottom with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth, bevel if you need sharp edges:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers  but i was able to do this but i can't make the next wavy edge for example

Comment: Oh OK m bad I thought it was the same wave we could see by transparence, your first image was rather low quality

Answer (score 4):

You could start with a cylinder with <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> loopcuts, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> in x-ray mode use <kbd>C</kbd> brush select, $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬆\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel up* to decrease brush size, mark just "one" vertex (opposite vertex will be selected too because of the x-ray mode), <kbd>O</kbd> enable the proportional editing* and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> move those vertices up, again using the mouse wheel to control the influence so the falloff at the edge of influence is nice:

[image] [image] [image]

Then like in moonboots' answer, you can extrude the bottom part:

[image]

And finally still with Proportional Editing enabled, scale the top down, plus shade smooth, subdivide (<kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>)…

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers  but i was able to do this but i can't make the next wavy edge for example